# I am working with laravel echo with redis and socket.io.It fails for presence and private channels

Tags: laravel, redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am working with laravel echo with redis and socket.io.It fails for presence and private channels

I am using this package for my server [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)

Everything works fine when I am using public channels but when I use private channels following error is logged in laravel-echo-server

```
     Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 503
⚠ [7:16:00 PM] - 155BcZ4cC_ieweeWAAAD could not be authenticated to presence-chat-message                    

</style>
</head><body id=ERR_CONNECT_FAIL>
<div id="titles">
<h1>ERROR</h1>
<h2>The requested URL could not be retrieved</h2>
</div>
<hr>

<div id="content">
<p>The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: <a href                           ="http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth">http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/au                           th</a></p>

<blockquote id="error">
<p><b>Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed.</b></p>
</blockquote>

<p id="sysmsg">The system returned: <i>(111) Connection refused</i></p>

<p>The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.</p>

<p>Your cache administrator is <a href="mailto:webmaster?subject=CacheErrorInfo%                           20-%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL&amp;body=CacheHost%3A%20routingserver-ProLiant-ML10-v2%0D                           %0AErrPage%3A%20ERR_CONNECT_FAIL%0D%0AErr%3A%20(111)%20Connection%20refused%0D%0                           ATimeStamp%3A%20Sat,%2022%20Apr%202017%2013%3A46%3A07%20GMT%0D%0A%0D%0AClientIP%                           3A%20172.16.0.69%0D%0AServerIP%3A%20localhost%0D%0A%0D%0AHTTP%20Request%3A%0D%0A                           POST%20%2Fbroadcasting%2Fauth%20HTTP%2F1.1%0AX-CSRF-TOKEN%3A%20vASD32FqeyddyxVxE                           2xIEwV59kjxgETldK9cLIXh%0D%0ACookie%3A%20Elgg_install%3Dk67c3s96b6ddp8pubp2g6lvt                           31%3B%20Elgg%3D5ncfp6re96lj5mron6nrmcjlf4%3B%20PHPSESSID%3Dj92vr9dsqq63o9q9a9q5t                           bu5q1%3B%20Phpstorm-4bea889c%3D96279c8c-c2d7-4275-8185-4e2526d58f0e%3B%20io%3DmT                           Kxolc1pbd-AO8CAAAC%3B%20XSRF-TOKEN%3DeyJpdiI6InM0eWxhMFlhYXlBb3BZVTQ5SThhNnc9PSI                           sInZhbHVlIjoiTFpObHVaZ2RtQzlyd0VvYnJHbVNYaDlsOStkcmxFeHo0SEJFTzlqcE01NTVpMDRyY1B                           3blRnN3ZnaHhaQzZLUVRXWWNKTGl3RDVFQWhIQnNlSjBhVEE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImYzYjI4NjgwY2I3YmZ                           jOGExNGM1ZjYzOGMwZDc2MzQwNjI5YmE4ZmUzMTJhNmRhMjk4MzkzZDJjMWRiZmM0MzgifQ%253D%253                           D%3B%20laravel_session%3DeyJpdiI6ImRsd3RNaWpnVWhDUGdqREgxVlNBeFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjo                           iQmxZQXl6bWQyN1dxM3QrZmhSdlRYK0ZxdHNpMFNKNnBXbytQQ1piREJmZWN5VHJDS2JXUXRWcjlkaVQ                           xRnBxdUdMM093czY5ZGw2S0xyb1NtWUNCbGc9PSIsIm1hYyI6Ijg0MDRjN2Q2MDRjMDYwYTc4MTQyZDU                           2MzU3MzZkZTc5NDkzZTM3OWEzMjVhM2MyYmFlZjVhZGQ1YzJkNjliNWUifQ%253D%253D%0D%0AX-Req                           uested-With%3A%20XMLHttpRequest%0D%0AContent-Type%3A%20application%2Fx-www-form-                           urlencoded%0D%0AProxy-Authorization%3A%20Basic%20dWVtOjEyMzQ1%0D%0AContent-Lengt                           h%3A%2034%0D%0AConnection%3A%20close%0D%0AHost%3A%20localhost%3A8000%0D%0A%0D%0A                           %0D%0A">webmaster</a>.</p>

<br>
</div>

<hr>
<!-- ERR_CONNECT_FAIL -->
</div>
</body></html>
```

**Following is my app.js,bootstrap.js and laravel-echo-server.json**

```
    const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data:{
      messages:[],

    },

    mounted:function() {

    axios.get('/message/2').then(response =>{

     for(i in response.data)
     {
         this.messages.push(response.data[i]);
     }

   });

   Echo.join('chat-message')
    .listen('MessageSentEvent', (data) => {

        console.log(data);

    });

   console.log("Done loading ");
   },

  methods:{

     addMessage(message) {
      // console.log(this.messages);
        this.messages.push(message);
        axios.post("ajax/message/send",message).then(response =>{
         });



        console.log('Added Message');
     }
 }


  });``
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
    import Echo from "laravel-echo"

    window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://localhost:6001',

    });
```

**laravel-echo-server.json**

```
    {
"authHost": "http://localhost:8000",
"authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
"clients": [
    {
        "appId": "c6efc75749e6d774",
        "key": "6a0910dcc0073a83d06df25ebc2590dc"
    },
    {
        "appId": "0c35b8cc253e901e",
        "key": "0c5c4f54754818ccf2ac0fc3f67809b5"
    }
],
"database": "redis",
"databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "password": "prince",
        "port": "6379"
    },
    "sqlite": {
        "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
},
"devMode": true,
"host": "localhost",
"port": "6001",
"protocol": "http",
"socketio": {},
"sslCertPath": "",
"sslKeyPath": ""
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per `laravel-echo-server.json` you have added the auth host route, so when you connect with laravel echo server, its check the auth route response to validate the authorisation.
`http://localhost:8000//broadcasting/auth` its not working so you getting this error, create the route `Route::post('broadcastAuth','HomeController@AuthSocket');`

check this repo for socket demo https://github.com/karoys/laravel-echo-server-vuejs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have uncommented **App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class** in config/app.php. This will create the broadcast auth route automatically